# SCSS font size not applying

Tags: sass, fonts, font-size

This is my first time using a website template which uses SCSS and thus I have no clue what to do with this.

I have the following code to set the text stying of my navbar links:

```
.nav-link{
    font: 500 15px/120px $rob;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    &:after{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I have set the min/max font size to be 15px/120px. However on my website it keeps appearing as 12px. What am I doing wrong?

Inspect element shows this:
[image]

But when I check the code it shows as this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of luck, you can find your way to the truth using Sass source maps. It seems like your template has this built-in, since you can see the file name `_header.scss:17` in your inspector code. (If source maps weren't enabled it would just say the name of the compiled `.css` file.)

In Chrome dev tools, you can ctrl-click the property value - in this case `500 15px/120px $rob` as shown in your screenshot.

This should take you to the "Sources" panel in dev tools and show the `.scss` file that compiles this specific value, and you can see if you have been editing the right file.

Since it's a common practice to split up Sass files into smaller files (or *partials*), there's a good chance your edits are being overwritten in one of the other partials in the template.

Comment: PS. The `15px/120px` value is not min/max font size, it's shorthand for font size/line height.